# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' -works ... and doesn't

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

Ok, still new to Ionic(4)/Angular(7), but I have two almost identical forms, one which works fine, the other doesn't and returns the error.
I have a 'Login' form, that works fine, and for reasons I won't go into, I decided to have a different form for 'Register' - So in the 'Login' form, if the user needs to register, the code navigate to the register page and optionally back again.
The login form works just fine, but navigating to the register page produces the error.
I have seen several other questions relating to this here, but none have one working and one not and most often seem to be the result of missing imports etc. Maybe thats my case too but I find that odd. I have scoured the text and maybe I'm just missing a stupid typo, cut and past error or something, but if so, I've been staring for a long time and still can't see it.

Here's the working Login form:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <form [formGroup]="credentialsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating" >Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="email" formControlName="Email" ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="Password" ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" [disabled]="!credentialsForm.valid">Login</ion-button>
        <ion-button expand="full" type="button" (click)="register()" [disabled]="!credentialsForm.valid">Register</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

The Typescript for the view:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from 

'./../../services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserData } from 'src/app/models/userdata';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})

export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  credentialsForm: FormGroup;
  private currentUser: UserData;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    ) {
      this.currentUser = new UserData();
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.credentialsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      Password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    });
  }


  onSubmit() {
    this.currentUser.Email = this.credentialsForm.value.Email;
    this.currentUser.Password = this.credentialsForm.value.Password;
    this.userService.saveUserStore(this.currentUser, false);
    this.authService.login(this.currentUser);
    this.router.navigate(['menu' , 'dashboard']);
  }



  register() {
    console.log('Going to Register Form');
    this.router.navigate(['register']);
  }
}
```

So here's the NOT working Register form:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button defaultHref="/login"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Register Page</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>


<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="Email" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" formControlName="Password" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Confirm Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" formControlName="ConfirmPassword" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" (click)="register()" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">Register</ion-button>
  <ion-button expand="full" type="button" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">Login</ion-button>

</form>

</ion-content>
```

... and the Typescript code for it:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserData } from 'src/app/models/userdata';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})

export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  private currentUser: UserData;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    ) {
      this.currentUser = new UserData();
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      Password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      ConfirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)] ]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(() => {
      // Call Login to automatically login the new user
      this.authService.login(this.registerForm.value);
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

Things I have tried:
Making the app module have the ReactiveForms Module and FormsModule imported. (doesnt make any difference so Ive commented it out for now as it works without for the login page).
Making the Register form blank (still didnt work)
Making the Register page empty but for a header (just to check the navigation- that worked)...
This just seems odd and I keep thinking I may have made a cut and paste error somewhere, but if so I cant see it so maybe another pair of eyes.
Many thanks...

Comment: Which NgModule is this RegisterPage part of? Is it lazy loaded? The ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule must be imported in the same NgModule.

Comment: Are you try (in both) add a *ngIf : `<form *ngIf="registerForm" [formGroup]="registerForm">`? At first registerForm it's null -only when execute ngOnInit the form take value, this can make Angular fails

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBenseler Thats it.!.. Noobie mistake not checking the module file where I had the FormsModule but not the REactiveFormsModule. Sorted and thank you - you are a star.